# The bar looks right. Why won't the animation work?

Tags: css, animation

I'm new to animation.    I pick some code up that had a demo that worked in the 5 browsers I'm testing in.  I'm on Windows 10 and have the latest versions of the 5 browsers I test in (Chrome, FF, edge IE, and Opera.  The CSS follows.

```css
.progress-bar {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 1.25em;
  width: 300px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.progress-value {
  background-color: MEDIUMBLUE;
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
  border-radius: 1.25em;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: progress 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -webkit-animation: progress 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.progress-value.green {
  background-color: MEDIUMSEAGREEN;
  animation: progress-3 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -webkit-animation: progress-3 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.progress-value.red {
  background-color: TOMATO;
  animation: progress-2 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -webkit-animation: progress-2 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}


/* animation */

@keyframes progress {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 55%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 55%;
  }
}

@keyframes progress-2 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-2 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@keyframes progress-3 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-3 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<DIV ID='dvLoading' STYLE='POSITION:relative;TOP:-300px;LEFT:30%;'>
  <DIV class='progress-bar'>
    <DIV class='progress-value' style='WIDTH:70%;'></DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

The bar looks like I hoped.   But there is no animation in any of the 5 browsers.

Comment: Nope, it works for me.

Comment: @MisirJafarov I see nothing on the snippet.

Comment: @MisirJafarov your edit suggestion solves the issue. Please put your edit as an answer

Comment: @Martin I think the issue is something else. It might not be due to additional style attribute which moves content out of the view area.

Comment: @MisirJafarov pre your edit the display did not work for me, post your edit the display did work as intended. Your edit is changing the source code given by the OP so is not a good edit, but as it solves the problem I think you should move it and set it as an answer.

Comment: @Martin how can I revert my unconfirmed edit?

Answer (score 1):

Here's working and better code for you. Instead of creating animation for each progress value, change width of child and show indicator inside the child and animate it once (from `width: 0%` to `width: 100%` width). I created a simple animating progress bar with 4 color variants.

```css
.progress {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

.progress>.progress-value {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.progress>.progress-value::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: progress-value 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -webkit-animation: progress-value 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  background: #666;
}

.progress>.progress-value.red::before {
  background: #f44;
}

.progress>.progress-value.green::before {
  background: #3f4;
}

.progress>.progress-value.blue::before {
  background: #54f;
}

@keyframes progress-value {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-value {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-value" style="width: 65%"></div>
</div>

<div style="height: 15px"></div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-value red" style="width: 95%"></div>
</div>

<div style="height: 15px"></div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-value green" style="width: 41%"></div>
</div>

<div style="height: 15px"></div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-value blue" style="width: 14%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is being used as a progress bar for a page load into an iframe.   I position the bar in the middle of the iframe.   Do you think the bar dynamic is playing out before I see it?   The indicator part of the bar is always at its styled width when I see it.

Comment: I've tried both snippets now with the same result.   Its probably me.  I just cant see it yet.

Comment: I end the indicator with an onload event in the iframe.  The html placement of the indicator is after the iframe.   It appears and places as intended, but does not animate.

Comment: Still no animation.   Frustrating.

Comment: @craigt I think you wanted to show page loading animation for iframe. But I don't think it's possible due security.

Comment: I pulled your code out of my program Misir and created a simple HTML file and it worked as it does here.  And I pulled the iframe out of my CGI code and it still does not work there.   The application I'm working on is in dHTML (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Perl 5, mod_perl, and Apache, on Windows 10.

Comment: @craigt I don't know how to resolve ur issue. :/ sorry

Comment: Thanks for the help.  At least I know it will work if I can find what is causing the interference.   Thats a good start.

Comment: Thinking there might be some sort of interaction with other parts of the program, I stripped out everything in the Perl/CGI program except the HTML skeleton, the CSS, and the DIVs.   It still does not work.

Comment: I loaded the HTML module with only the file loading indicator in the iframe in the CGI module and the animation worked.   But loading the animation into a div positioned on top of the iframe or any where else in the CGI and the animation does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What I did that works as I hoped is that I load the indicator as an HTML file into an object in the CGI process and position that object at the V/H center of the iframe. I put a 1 second lag in the JavaScript that's executed when the IFRAME content is loaded (ONLOAD) to turn the indicator off, to ensure that at least a little of the indicator is seen on a real fast load.   Thanks all.   ct